# How to modify or delete commit log in GIT after PUSH?

Tags: git

I used a very bad log template and has issued git push for that commit. How can I modify or delete this log entry?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer depends on whether or not other people have pulled your commit. If they have, then you're stuck with the bad template (or at least getting every local pull of the commit corrected probably isn't worth your time). If others haven't pulled it...

If it's the most recent commit, you can use `git commit --amend`.

If it's a commit a certain number in the past (call it commit `abcd1234`), then you can use `git rebase`:

```
git rebase -i abcd1234~1
```

In the interactive screen, change `pick` to `reword` for that commit, and leave the rest the same. The rebase will continue to that commit, then pause, allowing you to reword the commit message.

In either case, you'll need to "force push" the rebased branch up:

```
git push --force origin <branch> ;# using the `--force` flag
git push origin +:<branch> ;# same as above, just different syntax
```

Comment: Actually I am sure someone has pulled my commit. So is that to say it is NOT possible to fix this commit message?

Comment: @deepsky No, it is possible; it's just a serious pain. Both commands rewrite SHA1 hashes, which means your collaborators will have divergent branch histories. Unless they `reset` (which interrupts work in progress), you'll end up with redundant histories. If this sounds complex, it is. Unless the commit format is really grievous, it's probably not worth fixing.

Comment: @Christopher: They can `rebase`, which does not interrupt work in progress. But it's still action they need to do and at least a little bit understand to be able to do.

Comment: I think there is only 1 people pulled this commit and this commit message is really bad. So do I just need to ask him to do a new clone?

Comment: The repository can be configured to refuse forced pushes and if it's not your repository, you may not be able to bypass that check. In which case you can't fix it.

Comment: @deepsky: Not a new clone. Just `pull --rebase` (it may be configured to avoid rewinding the tracking branch, which would need additional option to allow, but I think it's allowed by default).

Comment: @deepsky Or just have him stash or commit any outstanding, uncommitted work, issue `git fetch`, then `git reset --hard <remote>/<branch>`, while checked out on the branch in question, of course.

Comment: @Christopher Thanks for your advice. I give up at last since doing this maybe harmful to our code repo (especially for me who is a newbie to git) and will definitely require someone else to re-commit their changes.